# Proving every compact set on $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Before starting proof, my knowledge includes followings;

(m represents the measurement function, $\lambda_*$ and $\lambda^*$ represent Lebesgue inner and outer measure)

i) Let $U$ is an $d_E$-open set then $U$ can be written by using disjoint intervals $\{I_n\}$ which are finite or countable sets and   $U= \bigcup_n I_n$ $\Rightarrow$ $m(U)=\sum_n m(I_n)$.

and

ii) Let $U$ and $V$ are $d_E$-open sets on $\mathbb{R}$

**$m(U)+m(V)=m(U \cup V) + m(U \cap V)$**

iii) $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded set. $E$ can be measured iff $\lambda^*(E)=\lambda_*(E)$

So I have **started proof** by determining my aim for measuring the compact set. So I think that because of measuring only open sets on $\mathbb{R}$ I have to write the compact set into combination of open sets then I can measure the compact set.

Let K is a compact set, U is an arbitrary open set and $K \subset U$. Because of $K \subset U$ we can re-write K as

$K= U \setminus (U\setminus K)$ and we have open and disjoint sets $U$ and $(U \setminus K)$  Now

$m(K)=m(U \setminus(U \setminus K))=........$

which I got for now. I don't know what am I going to do because I have no information about measuring the set difference. Also I didn't use the information iii) because while determining the Lebesgue inner measure,

$\lambda_*(E)=sup\{ m(K) : K \subset E, K compact\}$

I have to calculate a compact set's measure.

Thanks for any help

Comment: So you know that open sets are measurable right? To show that a compact set $K$ is measurable it suffices to show that the complement $K^C$ is measureable.

Comment: Also notice that since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff $K$ is closed so $K^C$ is open. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: but $K^c$ is not a superset of $K$ , so how should I start measuring in the fist place? @Nightgap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $\Bbb{R}$ every compact set is closed and bounded form Heine-Borel.

So it suffices to show that $K^c$ which is open,is measurable.

We have that in $\Bbb{R}$ every open set can be expressed as a countable union of disjoint open intervals,thus $$K^c=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n)$$

So we can show that every open interval $(a_n,b_n)$ is measurable.

A set is measurable on the real line if it can be approximated with respect to the Lebesgue $\text{outer}$ measure by open supersets.

In  other words:

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Take $B=(a,b+\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \supset (a,b)$ and we have that $m^*(B \setminus (a,b))=m^*(b,b+\frac{\epsilon}{2})=m^*(b,b+\frac{\epsilon}{2})=l(b,b+\frac{\epsilon}{2})\leq \epsilon$

where $l$ denotes the length of an inteval and we know that the outer measure of an interval is equal to its length.

So $(a,b)$ is measurable and from this you can deduce that $K^c$ is measurable as a countable union of measurable sets thus $K$ is measurable.

In general take the Lebesgue outer measure $m^*$.

A set $E$ on the real line is $m^*$ measurable if $m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A \cap E^c),\forall A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$.$(*)$

In general we consider an outer measure $\mu^*$ and we can construct the sigma algebra of subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ for instance with the property $(*)$.

Take a look at this:

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~ddeford/103_day4.pdf

With the Lebesgue outer measure $m*$ and the above technique we can construct the sigma algebra of $m^*-$measurable sets.

So the restriction of $m^*$ in this sigma algebra is the Lebesgue measure.

The argument i used in the proof just contains properties of the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

So now you can see that a set is measurable iff its complement is measurable from the defintion of a sigma algebra.

Comment: so with this proof, we assume that we know the property " $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is mesurable iff $E^c$ is mesurable". So how can I prove this one for use the proof above?

Comment: @AlperErdem i edited my question...take a look if you want.Hope this helps.