# Measure of a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be closed and bounded.

Define $E_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d \vert \exists y \in K$, $ \vert x - y \vert < \frac{1}{n} \}$

wish to show lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $m(E_n)$ = $m(K)$.

ATTEMPT:

So I wanted to use double sided inequality to show the equality holds.

NOTE: $E_1 \supset E_2 \supset E_2 ..$

I have a lemma stating: if additionally  $m(E_1) < + \infty$ then

lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $m(E_n)$ = $m(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_n$) **

(is ** lemma applicable her?)

using this, If I can make a claim stating $K = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n $ ( I doubt this is true) then I am done. But I feel like I am missing a subtlety. 
Sorry for being a noob, any help is greatly appreciated, I am new to measure theory and trying to learn!

Also, I have an observation, I would like to know is true:

Do all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ have finite (Lebesgue) measure.

Comment: If you have $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, then $d(x, K) = 0$, right? So since $K$ is closed, $x \in K$. So $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n} \subseteq K$. Also, since $K \subseteq E_{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, you also have $K \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, so $K = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$. Try to work out the details for yourself.

Comment: oh yes true, this I can workout, its a simple analysis/point set topology problem. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $r>0$, let $B(x,r)=\{y\mid d(x,y)<r\}$
be the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$. Note that 
$$
E_{n}=\bigcup_{x\in K}B(x,\frac{1}{n})
$$
which is a bounded (because $K$ is bounded) open set. In particular
$m(E_{n})<\infty$.

To show that $K=\cap_{n}E_{n}$. Clearly $E_{1}\supseteq E_{2}\supseteq\cdots\supseteq K$.
We only need to show that $\cap_{n}E_{n}\subseteq K$. Let $x\in\cap_{n}E_{n}$.
For each $n$, $x\in E_{n}\Rightarrow\exists y_{n}\in K$ such that
$x\in B(y_{n},\frac{1}{n})$. Since $K$ is compact, for the sequence
$(y_{n})$, there exists a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_{k}})$ and
$y\in K$ such that $y_{n_{k}}\rightarrow y$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.
Now 
\begin{eqnarray*}
d(x,y) & \leq & d(x,y_{n_{k}})+d(y_{n_{k}},y)\\
 & < & \frac{1}{n_{k}}+d(y_{n_{k}},y)\\
 & \rightarrow & 0,
\end{eqnarray*}
as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, $d(x,y)=0$ and hence $x=y\in K$.
This shows that $\cap_{n}E_{n}\subseteq K$.

Comment: got it thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

> I doubt this is true

It is, and your method is fine, once you've also checked that $m(E_1) < +\infty$.

> Do all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ have finite (Lebesgue) measure.

Yes. This follows from the Heine-Borel Theorem: all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are bounded, so are contained in some product of closed, bounded intervals, hence have measure bounded above by the measure of that product of closed, bounded intervals, which is finite. There's extra work to do to check that all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are measurable, but [indeed they are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536508/proving-every-compact-set-on-mathbbr-is-measurable/2536822#2536822).

Comment: Awesome!! thank you so much!! I am always very very hesitant on making claims unless I'm 100000% certain. I thought the equality was true but wanted to be extra certain, and yes Heine-Borel, luckily enough my point-set topology is relatively strong specially in comparison to my measure theory. again, thanks!!!!